# Android battery voltage unit discrepancies

Tags: java, android

I'm using the following line of code:

```
BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE
```

to get the battery voltage from 2 Android devices.

One gives me a value of `4347`, which I'm certain translates to `4347 mV` or `4.347 V`.

But on my other device, the value returned is `7`. This can't possibly mean the battery is outputting `.007 V`, so is there anything that the second value could represent?

The tablet returning the value of `7` is a **TF101**, which I believe has a total voltage output of `7.4 V` between 2 batteries. Could the `7` in this case be representing the Volts (not *milliVolts*)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably right that some device returns Voltage in Volt instead of mV. Your Asus tablet for example has 7.4[Volt] battery as you could see here: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Original-Genuine-Battery-for-ASUS-Eee-Pad-TF101-TR101-3300mAh-24Wh-C21-EP101-/191392703477 .

In my galaxy Young I get the same things. So I added this function:

```
public static float getBatteryVoltage(Intent batteryStatus){
    int voltage = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_VOLTAGE, -1);
    if (voltage > 1000)
        return voltage / 1000f;
    else
        return voltage;
}
```